# Are gaps in $n^2\sqrt{2}$ poissonian?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

I would like to know gaps about the sequence $n^2 \sqrt{2} \mod 1$.  [Van der Corput's trick](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/06/14/the-van-der-corputs-trick-and-equidistribution-on-nilmanifolds/) shows that $n^2 \sqrt{2}$ is equidistributed on the circle.  For large $N$, the fraction
$$ \frac{\# \{ 1 \leq i \leq N: a < n^2 \sqrt{2} \mod 1 < b \} }{N} \approx b-a.$$
Do the spacings between these values approach the Poisson distribution (as they would for uniformly random numbers)?  Is there a proof of this involving Homogenous spaces?  This is different from Elkies and McMullen's paper where they consider [$\sqrt{n}\mod 1$](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/papers/sqrts/sqrts.pdf) and relate it to the 5D space of Euclidean lattices.

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13):

Rudnick and Sarnak (MR1628282) conjecture that any not-too-well-approximable $\alpha$ has this property in place of $\sqrt{2}$, in particular any algebraic number should have this property. They prove that almost every $\alpha$ (in the Lebesgue sense) have this property, but no specific $\alpha$ has been exhibited so far. Rudnick-Sarnak-Zaharescu (MR1839285) and Zaharescu (MR1957276) have examined what happens for too-well-approximable $\alpha$'s. The above mentioned papers and their AMS reviews should serve as good starting points.